# How do I fix pip freeze when looking for packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

So Im trying to host a discord bot but when I get to the requirements.txt bit I was told that when I want to find out which packages I need to include in the txt file I can use pip freeze in the command prompt but all I get is this error:

```
WARNING: Could not generate requirement for distribution -ip 20.2.3 (c:\python39\lib\site-packages): Parse error at "'-ip==20.'": Expected W:(abcd...)
```

WARNING: Could not generate requirement for distribution - p (c:\python39\lib\site-packages): Parse error at "'-===p'": Expected W:(abcd...)

any ideas?

Comment: what command are you using to get this error?

Comment: @Gulzar `pip freeze`